# pip install -find-links search order

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I am trying to install a package built by myself, but there is a package with same name on PYPI.

I tried with `pip install my_package==1.2.0 --find-links page_html_with_link_to_package`, but it downloaded the package from PYPI with same version 1.2.0.

Then I tried with `pip install my_package==1.2.0 --find-links page_html_with_link_to_package --no-index`, and it downloaded my package.

It's that normal? And if there is any other ways to download my package without `--no-index`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is normal. Check these examples below on official documentation of `pip install`, example [9. Install from alternative package repositories](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#examples) > `Install from a local flat directory containing archives (and don’t scan indexes):`

```
pip install --no-index --find-links=file:///local/dir/ SomePackage
pip install --no-index --find-links=/local/dir/ SomePackage
pip install --no-index --find-links=relative/dir/ SomePackage
```

or if you have it hosted somewhere else, then you can just use:

`pip install --index-url http://my.package.repo/simple/ SomePackage`

Comment: Will it still work if there's a dependency that is in a repo? Let's say SomePackage depends on numpy...